# React JS -- Adding multiple Children Node to a single Node without overwriting current contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Please see the code below.
In the return statement, I am trying to add components with the structure:

- inputs

  - inputId

    - rowId

      1. value
      2. isValid
    - rowId

      1. value
      2. isValid
  - inputId

    - rowId

      1. value
      2. isValid
    - rowId

      1. value
      2. isValid

However, when I try to use spread syntax to preserve the state and simply add nodes to the state, I cannot load the already-defined rowId components for a specific inputId because syntax such as the following doesn't work `...state.inputs.[action.inputId].rowId`.

What is currently happens is that "state" only ever holds one rowId component (the latest one) because it overwrites the previous ones because I cannot correctly use spread syntax to preserve initial state.

Code:

```
const formReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INPUT_CHANGE':
      let formIsValid = true;
      for (const inputId in state.inputs) {
        if (inputId === action.inputId) {
          formIsValid = formIsValid && action.isValid;
        } else {
          formIsValid = formIsValid && state.inputs[inputId].isValid;
        }
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        inputs: {
          ...state.inputs,
          [action.inputId]: { 
              [action.rowId]: {     //This is the problematic line ... I would like to execute ' ...state.inputs.[action.inputId].rowId ' before this line
                value: action.value, 
                isValid: action.isValid 
              }   
          }
        },
        isValid: formIsValid
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code(logic) really difficult to read.

Anyway, it seems you are miss using object key as variable.

Use :

```
...state.inputs[action.inputId].rowId
```

Instead of this :

```
...state.inputs.[action.inputId].rowId
```

Comment: Sorry for the difficulty to read, but this worked! Using ...state.inputs[action.inputId] worked! Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Please accept my answer so i will be flattered:D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need `...state.inputs[action.inputId]`:

```js
return {
    ...state,
    inputs: {
        ...state.inputs,
        [action.inputId]: { 
            ...state.inputs[action.inputId],
            [action.rowId]: {     
                // Another example: if you would also need to merge here with the previous state, you would need:               
                // ...(state.inputs[action.inputId] ? state.inputs[action.inputId][action.rowId] : [],
                // OR if optional chaining operator is supported:
                // ...state.inputs[action.inputId]?.[action.inputId],
                value: action.value, 
                isValid: action.isValid 
            }   
        }
    },
    isValid: formIsValid
};
```

(I hope there's no syntax error).

Or use something like [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer) if you want more flexibility/readability when working with immutable data.